# Xcode 12 iOS 14.0.1 app crashes while launching on device when closed or disconnected from cable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I updated my iPhone 8 to iOS 14.0.1 and Xcode to version 12. When I run my flutter app on my phone with xcode, it installs the newest version to my iPhone. But it crashes when I do one on the following things:

- If I disconnect my phone from my MacBook
- If I close the app (even with connected to MacBook)and try to open it screen is fading into half transparent black and fading back. It wont open again

What I already tried:

- unplug device in xcode
- restarted everything (xcode, vscode, mac, disconnected phone)

Does any one else have similar issue? Does anyone know what to do?
Maybe iOS14.0.1 is still unsupported for xcode?

Comment: I found this on the official Flutter docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-14 apparently its a known issue with iOS 14